# Match multiple field with redis hscan command

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

i use redis for caching my mongodb document with hmset command

```
hmset uId username hamet
hmset uId meta.avatar testString
hmset uId meta.email testString
```

i need to query like this

```
hscan uId 0 MATCH username meta.* // and more fields
```

but i got invalid syntax error

is there a way to query like this?

Comment: It seems you know the exact field name, and so you can simply use `hmget uId username meta.avatar meta.email` and it would fetch those fields. Right?

Comment: Yes in this case i can use hmget but when i want to fetch all fields starting with meta and fields with username, how can i query this?

Comment: Sometimes i need get fields matching pattern and some key with exact field name

Comment: hscan only takes a single pattern. You will have to issue multiple hscan commands in a pipeline, one for each of your patterns, and then a single hmget command for exact field names.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with another command or something else?

Comment: Depends on how many fields you have. If you have say less than 20 fields, then just fetch all the field names using `hkeys`, filter in javascript, and then fetch them all in 1 single `hmget`. If you have a large number of fields and a large number of patterns to search, it'd be better to write a lua script.

Comment: Tnq, i think i have to write lua script, do you have any solution to write script for this case?